# How can I access a property of an object using another property

Tags: angular, typescript, object

The requirement is to display some details based on user selected dropdown.

Example:
If User selects 1 from dropdown A should be displayed in the page.

My question is how can I access the "name" property of the object using selected dropdown value as "id" property?

**Book.ts**

```
export class Book
{
    id!:number;
    name!:string;
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Book } from './book';
import { GetService } from './get.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit(){}

  constructor(private service:GetService,){}

  books!: Book;
  selectedId!:Number
  selectedObj:Number[]=[1,2,3,4]

  details(){
    this.service.getDetails().subscribe(hero=>
      {
        this.books=hero;
        console.log(hero)
      })
  }

}
```

**service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Book } from './book';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GetService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getDetails():Observable<Book>{
    return this.http.get<Book>("assets/book-details.json")

  }
}
```

**book-details.json**

```
[
    {"id":1,"name":"A"},
    {"id":2,"name":"B"},
    {"id":3,"name":"C"},
    {"id":4,"name":"D"}
]
```

**app-component.html**

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedId" (change)="details()">
        <option *ngFor="let b of selectedObj" [value]="b">{{b}}</option>
    </select`
    <p>{{books}}</p>
</body>
```

Comment: You can use [find method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) of an array: `const bookSelected=this.books.find(x=>x.id==this.selectedID)`

Answer (score 0):

If the `books` array of objects can itself be used to create the options of the `<select>` element, you can modify its definition in your template.html file as shown below,

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedID">
  <option *ngFor="let book of books" [value]="book.name">{{book.id}}</option>
</select>

<span>{{selectedID}}<span>
```

In the above code snippet, `books` is an array of objects containing the response fetched via the injectable service `GetService`. For this, the `details` function needs to be invoked inside the `OnInit` lifecycle hook, as shown below.

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {}

  constructor(private service: GetService) {}

  books: Book;
  selectedID: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.details();
  }

  details() {
    this.service.getDetails().subscribe(hero => {
      this.books = hero;
      console.log(hero)
    })
  }

}
```

Or,

You filter the `books` array of objects on the basis of `selectedID` and bind the filtered value to a variable in your template.html file, as shown in the following code snippet.

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service: GetService, ) {}

  books: Book;
  selectedId: Number;
  selectedObj: Number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4];

  selectedBook: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.details();
  }

  filterBooks() {
    this.selectedBook = this.books.find(book => book.id == this.selectedID);
    console.log(this.selectedBook);
  }

}
```

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedId" (change)="filterBooks()">
  <option *ngFor="let b of selectedObj" [value]="b">{{b}}</option>
</select>

<p>{{selectedBook.name}}</p>
```

**Note**: In the above approach, the method to filter `books` array of objects will need to be invoked on every `change` event of the `<select>` element.